# Export audio(aiff) file format from .mov in Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avplayerlayer

Friend im tried exporting from .mov to .aif used below code in my application. File was exporting correclty. But the file format type is AAC. So Can you please tell me how to export aif format in cocoa application. But file was saved .aif file only. But its showing only AAC. I want to AIFF format.

Showing the Bit per sample is nothing in that export file.But i manually export mov to m4a format from quciktime player.After i export m4a to aiff export from itune. Format was correctly.Please tel me where i have missed or wrongly

```
[manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.aif"];

    //Remove Existing File
    [manager removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL]; // output path;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
```

Comment: You will need to convert from the audio format used in mov to aiff.

Comment: @volker Can you please suggest the piece of code to check ?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late, but in case... `AVFileTypeAIFF` instead of `AVFileTypeAppleM4A`;